# Git Hooks - post-merge hook file not exist

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

I am new to Git versioning system.
I have installed git on my Ubuntu machine.
Only following hooks a available.

```
applypatch-msg.sample
commit-msg.sample
post-update.sample
pre-applypatch.sample
pre-commit.sample
prepare-commit-msg.sample
pre-push.sample
pre-rebase.sample
update.sample
```

Where is the "post-merge" hook file?

Answer (score 2):

The post-merge hook was introduced in [commit 4623291 (git 1.5.4, Sept 2007)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46232915d5ac84fb033ad395bbf161c9645c42c9), but that never included a `post-merge.sample` file.

```
diff --git a/git-merge.sh b/git-merge.sh
index 3a01db0..66e48b3 100755
--- a/git-merge.sh
+++ b/git-merge.sh
@@ -97,6 +97,19 @@ finish () {
                fi
                ;;
        esac
+
+       # Run a post-merge hook
+        if test -x "$GIT_DIR"/hooks/post-merge
+        then
+           case "$squash" in
+           t)
+                "$GIT_DIR"/hooks/post-merge 1
+               ;;
+           '')
+                "$GIT_DIR"/hooks/post-merge 0
+               ;;
+           esac
+        fi
 }
```

So you can create a `post-merge` file (in the usual place `.git/hooks/`) if you need that hook. But you don't have any sample at the same place as the others.

[commit af6fb4c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af6fb4c822a5a65c7671d810127171759dff38f6) did add reference a `post-merge` sample though, by calling:

[**`git/git/contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl)

That script includes:

> To restore permissions/ownership data, place this script in your `.git/hooks` directory and enable a `post-merge` hook with the following lines:

```
  #!/bin/sh
 . git-sh-setup
 $GIT_DIR/hooks/setgitperms.perl -w
```

Comment: Is it...?.Thank you very much!